# Deleting first N rows of table using hibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to delete first 'N' rows from table using HibernateTemplate() object. How to specify it to the HibernateTemplate object?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name WHERE rowid IN
(SELECT rowid FROM table_name WHERE rownum <= &no_of_rows_to_keep);
```